# Mapping an object that contains an observablearray that contains an observablearray

Tags: json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Can anybody suggest why the mapping below hasn't worked properly? The table renders correctly with the correct amount of rows. `<td data-bind="text: Rank"></td>` parses as expected too but no other data-binds were successful. However, the debugger is not returning any errors.

**Json**

[{"Rank":1,"IntegerList":{"IntegerListID":14,"Direction":"Ascending","Performance":451,"Integers":[{"IntegerValue":0},{"IntegerValue":0}]}},{"Rank":2,"IntegerList":{"IntegerListID":13,"Direction":"Ascending","Performance":504,"Integers":[{"IntegerValue":0},{"IntegerValue":0}]}},{"Rank":3,"IntegerList":{"IntegerListID":18,"Direction":"Ascending","Performance":514,"Integers":[{"IntegerValue":1},{"IntegerValue":2}]}},{"Rank":4,"IntegerList":{"IntegerListID":19,"Direction":"Ascending","Performance":515,"Integers":[{"IntegerValue":2},{"IntegerValue":3},{"IntegerValue":4}]}}]

**Knockout**

```
function rankedIntegerLists(data) {
    this.Rank = data.Rank;
    this.IntegerList = ko.observableArray([this.IntegerListID = data.IntegerListID,
                                           this.Performance = data.Performance,
                                           this.Direction = data.Direction,
                                           this.Integers = ko.observableArray(data.Integers)]);
    }

$.getJSON("/Home/GetIntegerLists", function (allData) {
    var mappedIntegers = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new rankedIntegerLists(item) });
    viewModel.integerlists(mappedIntegers);
});

viewModel.integerlists = ko.observableArray([]);
```

**HTML**

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: integerlists">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Rank"></td>
        <td>
            <ul class="integers" data-bind="foreach: IntegerList.Integers">
                <li data-bind="text: IntegerValue"></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: IntegerList.Direction"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: IntegerList.Performance"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Edit**

ko.toJSON($data, null, 2) return the below. Clearly it's the `IntegerList` observablearray that isn't mapped.

```
"integerlists": [
{
  "Rank": 1,
  "IntegerList": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ]
},
{
  "Rank": 2,
  "IntegerList": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ]
},
{
  "Rank": 3,
  "IntegerList": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ]
},
{
  "Rank": 4,
  "IntegerList": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ]
},
{
  "Rank": 5,
  "IntegerList": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ]
}]
```

Comment: Add this to your view, it may help to debug what values have been mapped - <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre> inside of your foreach.

Comment: Aha - that is useful. Pretty much confirms what I thought (see edited question). I'm not sure how to resolve the issue though.

Comment: Better still, install this Chrome extension for Knockout - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en

It lets you inspect the context for any element on the page. Has been invaluable for my Knockout development.

Comment: Not really better in this situation - if the mapping extension isn't mapping the properties then the context will never assign a tracer and watch the values...  But it is a useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying that this is your only problem or going to fix your problem specifically, but I think it is better practice to use a model in this situation for debugging and for code clarity.  Also, use `var self = this` in your code to ensure that you are still in the correct scope / context.

```
function integerListModel(data) {
   var self = this;
   self.IntegerListID = ko.observable(data.IntegerListID);
   self.Performance = ko.observable(data.Performance);
   self.Direction = ko.observable(data.Direction);
   self.Integers = ko.observableArray(data.Integers);
}

function rankedIntegerLists(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Rank = data.Rank;
    self.IntegerList = new integerListModel(data);
}
```

Try to update your code and throw some console.log's in there if you still aren't getting data, it may help you to figure out why.